# JCO Error - Unhandled exception at 0x77106214 in java.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted

Tags: spring-boot, jvm, java-native-interface, sapb1

I am getting error

```
Unhandled exception at 0x77106214 in java.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted
```

On long running of application in server tomcat 8, java 8. In the application I am connecting SAPB1 with JCO library. It work well for some time, but after couple of hours JVM get crashed and getting an error as mentioned above.
My code was made from [this](https://github.com/rafalrozmus/java-and-sap-business-one/blob/master/Java%20And%20SAP%20Business%20One%20Examples/src/ConnectToServer.java) helpful reference. And in the application I am using a sync application(scheduled job) to get data from SAPB1. From the error It seems like there is an error while using JNI, that error is propagated back to JVM hence it get crashed.

*Used JcoQuery is mentioned below*

> SELECT DocEntry, DocNum, CardName, CardCode, docTotal, UpdateTS,
>   UpdateDate, DocDate, Comments, DocStatus, DocDueDate, ReceiptNum FROM
>   OPOR WHERE ObjType=22 AND convert (datetime,(SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,
>   CONVERT(CHAR(8), UpdateDate, 112) + ' ' + CONVERT(CHAR(8), (SELECT
>   CAST(LEFT(RIGHT('000000' + CAST(UpdateTS AS VARCHAR), 6), 2) + ':' +
>   RIGHT(LEFT(RIGHT('000000' + CAST(UpdateTS AS VARCHAR), 6), 4), 2) +
>   ':' + RIGHT('000000' + CAST(UpdateTS AS VARCHAR), 2)  AS TIME)),
>   108)))) > convert (datetime,(SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8),
>   CAST('2018-10-19 15:11:00.60' AS DATE), 112) + ' ' + CONVERT(CHAR(8),
>   (SELECT CAST(LEFT(RIGHT('000000' + CAST('1233' AS VARCHAR), 6), 2) +
>   ':' + RIGHT(LEFT(RIGHT('000000' + CAST('1233' AS VARCHAR), 6), 4), 2)
>   + ':' + RIGHT('000000' + CAST('1233' AS VARCHAR), 2)  AS TIME)), 108)))) ORDER BY DocNum

*Used code is given below*

```
private <T> List<T> getData(Class<T> klazz, ICompany company, JcoQuery jcoQuery) throws Exception {
        IRecordset recordSet = null;
        List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
        try {
            recordSet = SBOCOMUtil.newRecordset(company);
            String query = jcoQuery.getQuery();
            System.out.println("Query : "+query);
            List<String> fieldNameList = jcoQuery.getResultFieldList();
            recordSet.doQuery(query);
            int index = recordSet.getRecordCount();
            // print out column names first - CardCode(item 0) and CardName(item 1)
            System.out.println(recordSet.getFields().item(0).getName() + ":" +recordSet.getFields().item(0).getValue()
                + "\t\t"
                + recordSet.getFields().item(1).getName() + ":" + recordSet.getFields().item(1).getValue()
            );
            recordSet.moveFirst();
            // iterate through all rows
            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
                result.add(setObject(klazz, fieldNameList, recordSet));
                recordSet.moveNext();
            } 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        } finally {
            try {
                recordSet.release();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

*Error is as mentioned in this* [link](https://jpst.it/1rb4j)

```
Stack: [0x15810000,0x15860000], sp=0x1585d858, free space=310k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C [ntdll.dll+0x41f49]
C [ntdll.dll+0x41d6a]
C [sbojni.dll+0xa465]
C [sbojni.dll+0x1b31]
C [sbojni.dll+0x1e99]
J 5321 com.sap.smb.sbo.wrapper.com.Dispatch.invokev(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;III[Lcom/sap/smb/sbo/wrapper/com/Variant;[I)Lcom/sap/smb/sbo/wrapper/com/Variant; (0 bytes) @ 0x027aa54c [0x027aa460+0xec]
J 5320 C1 com.sap.smb.sbo.wrapper.com.Dispatch.invokev(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;I[Lcom/sap/smb/sbo/wrapper/com/Variant;[I)Lcom/sap/smb/sbo/wrapper/com/Variant; (31 bytes) @ 0x0263f1c8 [0x0263f160+0x68]
j com.sap.smb.sbo.wrapper.com.Dispatch.get(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/sap/smb/sbo/wrapper/com/Variant;+10
j com.sap.smb.sbo.api.Company.getCompanyName()Ljava/lang/String;+6
j com.gtl.app.sapb1.adapter.sabpb1.connection.JcoCompanyConnector.connect()Z+246
j com.gtl.app.sapb1.adapter.sabpb1.connection.JcoDataFetcher.getData(Ljava/lang/Class;Lcom/gtl/app/sapb1/adapter/sabpb1/query/JcoQuery;)Ljava/util/List;+6
j com.gtl.app.sapb1.adapter.service.impl.PurchaseOrderServiceImpl.getPurchaseOrderList(Lcom/gtl/app/erp/api/service/request/GetPurchaseOrderListRequest;)Lcom/gtl/app/erp/api/service/response/GetPurchaseOrderListResponse;+63
j com.gtl.app.sapb1.adapter.controller.PurchaseOrderController.getPurchaseOrderList(Lcom/gtl/app/erp/api/service/request/GetPurchaseOrderListRequest;)Lorg/springframework/http/ResponseEntity;+5
j sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor92.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+40
J 204 C1 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (10 bytes) @ 0x02680bc0 [0x02680b90+0x30]
```

---

```
Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 60835.818 Thread 0x11bf7000 Exception <a 'com/sap/smb/sbo/wrapper/com/ComFailException'> (0x0468e300) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u172\10810\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 62479.265 Thread 0x11bf7000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException': -1> (0x04deef38) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u172\10810\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\interpreterRuntime.cpp, line 366]
Event: 62479.265 Thread 0x11bf7000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException': -1> (0x04def158) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u172\10810\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\interpreterRuntime.cpp, line 366]
Event: 62479.630 Thread 0x11bf3c00 Exception <a 'java/io/IOException'> (0x046e8660) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u172\10810\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 66178.572 Thread 0x24ddd800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException': 83> (0x05d6cc80) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u172\10810\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\interpreterRuntime.cpp, line 366]
Event: 66178.583 Thread 0x24ddd800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException': 31> (0x05d97808) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u172\10810\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\interpreterRuntime.cpp, line 366]
Event: 66178.585 Thread 0x24ddd800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException': 60> (0x05d9f518) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u172\10810\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\interpreterRuntime.cpp, line 366]
Event: 66178.586 Thread 0x24ddd800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException': 88> (0x05da1608) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u172\10810\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\interpreterRuntime.cpp, line 366]
Event: 66178.588 Thread 0x24ddd800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException': 31> (0x05db1a70) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u172\10810\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\interpreterRuntime.cpp, line 366]
Event: 66392.516 Thread 0x132bf400 Exception <a 'com/sap/smb/sbo/wrapper/com/ComFailException'> (0x0497bc30) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u172\10810\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709]
```

Comment: I don't see any SAP JCo code here. And the error is also **no** error from JCo. JCo is not contained in the stack trace and a JCo native library has **not** even been loaded.

Comment: Really?? I wonder what these objects are :  ICompany,  JcoQuery, jcoQuery.getResultFieldList() . com.sap.smb.sbo.wrapper.com.Dispatch.invokev, om.sap.smb.sbo.wrapper.com.Dispatch.get seems like error to me. If you like to help, help. Please don't under-appreciate my work.  And for the sake, Its not SAP. Its SAPB1.

Comment: I see that your linked GitHub code also speaks of "JCO libraries". This is not what >99% of the people mean when speaking of "JCO" in the context of SAP. JCo is the common abbreviation for the [SAP Java Connector](https://support.sap.com/jco) and is also what your specified tag 'jco' stands for. That seems to be source of the confusion here. I am helping now with deleting the wrongly set tag 'jco'. Unfortunately I cannot further help with the error itself, as I do not know this SAP Business One product.

Comment: Can you please you go through this link https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/116707 . SAPB1 is also using JCO. The link is from SAP itself. There is no other tag That I can use here, That's why I have to use it here